# Strange symbol in style file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, legend

I have a geological style file [Biblioteca_CPRM_v2](https://we.tl/pDxy8QQCkV).

But when I open it it appears like this
[image]

Should look like with this
[image]

I guess it may be something in style fonts. Any idea?

Comment: Looks ok to me ... Just not the styles you wanted?

Comment: You'll need to give more information.  What about it doesn't appear how it should?  Is it one specific symbol that's not right (as implied by your title) or do you not want to see any of those symbols?  What shows up if you click the "Style References" button in the bottom-right?

Comment: It looks like it's referencing a font that doesn't exist. Were there fonts that came with the style that you need to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS marker/point symbols are typically created using symbols from installed fonts. When ArcGIS Desktop is installed it adds a number of fonts into the Windows Fonts folder (for example 73 new fonts were installed by ArcGIS 10.5 on my PC).

It looks like whoever created your new Style file used a font or fonts that you do not have installed on your PC, so ArcGIS is defaulting to a different (alphabetic) font to substitute the symbol. The markers in each symbol font are stored in the position of letters in a standard alphabetic font, which is why you are seeing what look like letters through your symbols.

To fix this you will either need to obtain and install the missing font, or modify each symbol to use a character from a different symbol font.

I have opened your Style file in Microsoft Access and have been unable to determine the name of the fonts used, so am unable to help with that.  You will need to contact the style creator to obtain the font, or at least find out which font it should be using.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [missing font](http://www.aguas.sc.gov.br/base-documental/documentos?jsmallfib=1&dir=JSROOT/Diretoria%20de%20Recursos%20Hidricos/Publicacoes/Aguas%20Subterraneas/Simbologias%20ESRI). Now it's OK!

[image]

Thanks for your help.